# Convert CSV to txt and start new line every 10 values using Python

Tags: python, file, text, csv, split

I have a csv file with an array of values 324 rows and 495 columns. All the values for each row and col are the same.

I need to have this array split up so that every 10 values is put in a new row. So for each of the 324 rows, there will be 49 full columns with 10 values and 1 column with 5 values (495 col / 10 values = 49 new rows with 10 values and 1 new row with 5 values). Then go to the next row and so on for 324 rows.

The trouble i'm having is listed as follows:

1. line.split(",") does not seem to be doing anything
2. Everything after the line.split doesn't seem to do anything either
3. i'm not sure my for newrow in range...is correct
4. I haven't put in the write output to text file yet, i think it should be outFile.write(something goes here, not sure what)
5. i put "\n" after print statement, but it just printed it out

I'm a beginner programmer.

Script:

```
import string
import sys

# open csv file...in read mode
inFile= open("CSVFile", 'r')
outFile= open("TextFile.txt", 'w')


for line in inFile:
    elmCellSize = line.split(",")
    for newrow in range(0, len(elmCellSize)):
        if (newrow/10) == int(newrow/10):
            print  elmCellSize[0:10]   

outFile.close()
inFile.close()
```

Comment: use http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html for reading CSV. Find some examples and study them.

Comment: I tried this but it still didn't delimit the commas: with open('elm_4feb13_ascii.csv', 'rb') as inFile:
    reader = csv.reader(inFile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if row == int(row/10):
            print row
            break

Comment: Are you sure the input CSV file is comma delimited?

Comment: If "All the values for each row and col are the same" why are you storing this in a file in the first place and secondly what's the point of putting them all into another having just a different form-factor?

Comment: The `for row in reader: if row == int(row/10): print row; break` doesn't work because `row` is a list of the values just read from a line of the input file, not an integer (so the condition will never be True).

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using the csv module, but I can give some advice anyway.

One problem you're having is that when you say `print elmCellSize[0:10]`, you are always taking the first 10 elements, not the most recent 10 elements.  Depending on how you want to do this, you could keep a string to remember the most recent 10 elements.  I'll show an example below, after mentioning a few things that you can fix with your code.

First note that `line.split(',')` returns a list.  So your choice of variable name `elmCellSize` is a little misleading.  If you were to say `lineList = line.split(',')` it might make more sense?  Or if you were to say `lineSize = len(line.split(','))` and use that?

Also (although I don't know anything about Python 2.x) I think `xrange` is a function for Python 2.x which is more efficient than `range`, although it works exactly the same way.

Instead of saying `if (newrow/10) == int(newrow/10)`, you can actually say `if index % 10 == 0`, to check if index is a multiple of 10.  `%` can be thought of as 'remainder', so it will give the remainder of `newrow` when divided by `10`.  (Ex: 5 % 10 = 5; 17 % 10 = 7; 30 % 10 = 0)

Now instead of printing `[0:10]`, which will always print the first 10 elements, you want to print from the current index back 10 spaces.  So you can say `print lineList[index-10:index]` in order to print the most recent 10 elements.

In the end you'll have something like

```
...
lineList = line.split(',') # Really, you should use csv reader
# Open the file to write to
with open('yourfile.ext', 'w') as f:
    # iterate through the line
    for index, value in enumerate(lineList):
        if index % 10 == 0 and index != 0:
            # Write the last 10 values to the file, separated by commas
            f.write(','.join(lineList[index-10:index]))
            # new line
            f.write('\n')
            # print
            print lineList[index-10:index]
```

I'm certainly not an expert, but I hope this helps!

Comment: `range(1, n)` gives 1 through n-1. `range(n-1)` gives 0 through n-2. The start value is included but the stop value is excluded.

Comment: Is the yourfile.ext supposed to be the textFile.txt?

Comment: still having problems, workin on it though, thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this script almost works, i think.

The problem right now is that it stops writing to the outFile after the 1st 49 rows. It makes the 10 columns for 49 rows, but there should be a 50th row with only 5 columns because each row from the CSV file is 495 columns. So the current script writes out the last 10 values to a new row 49 times, but it doesn;t get those extra 5. Plus, it has to do this another 323 times becasue the original CSV file has 324 rows.

So, i think the problem now is possibly in the last if statement, maybe an else statement is needed, but my elif statement did not do anything. I want it to say if the 6th value in the list is an end of line character ('\n'), then write the 5 values in the list prioir to the end of line...it didn't work.

Thanks for all the help so far, i appreciate it!

Here is the script:

```
import string
#import sys
#import csv

# open csv file...in read mode
inFile= open("CSVFile.csv", 'r')
outFile= open("TextFile.txt", 'w')



for line in inFile:
    lineList = line.split(',') # Really, you should use csv reader
# Open the file to write to
    with open('outFile', 'w') as outFile:
        # iterate through the line
        for index, value in enumerate(lineList):
            if index % 10 == 0 and index != 0:
                # Write the last 10 values to the file, separated by space
                outFile.write('\t'.join(lineList[index-10:index]))
                # new line
                outFile.write('\n')
                # print
                print lineList[index-10:index]
elif lineList[6] == '\n':
            # Write the last 5 values to the file, separated by space
                outFile.write(' '.join(lineList[index-5:index]))
                # new line
                outFile.write('\n')
                # print
                print lineList[index-:index]

outFile.close()
inFile.close()
```